# Very basic and simple db file for C# desktop app

Tags: c#, database, windows, desktop-application

I realize this might be a stupid question, but my GoogleFu seems to be letting me down here.

I'm writing a very simple little app for myself, but I want to be able to store some data to a db file. Currently I'm using SQLite and although it works I would like something even simpler if possible which does not require me to create tables and columns before hand. Also, for some reason the SQLite takes it's sweet time when making the first connection on app startup. I've not been able to figure out why and it's becoming somewhat tiresome to have to wait 30-60sec for the first connection and that's with it on an SSD. After that first connection it's perfectly fine and responsive. But I'm getting off topic...

I found db4o and that seemed like it was what I wanted, but it seems that project is dead. I just want the simplest and most basic option that will give me some database like capabilities where I can Insert, Update, and Delete records.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use any db you like :) SQLexpress or access, or csv, or raw storage.. :D

Comment: Or xml: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84sxtbxh(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: https://sqlite.org/

Comment: I did consider serializing my array of objects to XML and then just dump that to a text file on app close and then load it on app startup, but if the app crashes you could loose data. I suppose I could just do dumps to the file every time a change to the data is made. Although performance is not really a concern, that approach just seems... wrong. It will work though and I won't have any dependencies...

Comment: @HAckerman I don't want to use SQLite as stated in my post. I am in this weird position where a plain text file won't really cut it and even SQLite feels like overkill.

Comment: I've had some success with [LiteDB](http://www.litedb.org/) - open-source and very lightweight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. I ended up just serializing my C# object to XML and dumping that to a text file every time a change is made to the object. Then at app startup I just read the text and deserialize the XML back into an object.

This way I can add or change the object's definition with ease while I develop the application and don't need to create or update any tables or columns like I had to with a SQLite DB. I also don't have any dependencies other than .net 4.0.

If I was going to store something like Client Info on a crappy desktop application then I would use SQLite as the data would have some importance.

I'm just storing a list of url's (Along with some other data) that can easily be replaced if the data were to be lost.

I do mostly front end dev work and some MS SQL. As such my knowledge with database tech in general kinda sucks, so I've learned about some other DB tech.

Thanks Again

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, the best suggestion I could make is to figure out the latency issue you're having with SQLite and continue using it.  There are other options to be sure, but SQLite is a very elegant solution to local data storage.

That said, if you're insisting on something different but don't want flat-file, I guess you could try [xBase](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xbase-engine-for-C-Sharp-and-VB-Net/)